# Import address table yields incorrect RVA for import name

Tags: c++, winapi, portable-executable

I'm having trouble with the Win32 NT headers giving me odd RVA's for import names. Here is the relevant code that is giving me the problem:

```
//Get a pointer to the import table
PIMAGE_IMPORT_DESCRIPTOR piidImportTableAddr; 
piidImportTableAddr = (PIMAGE_IMPORT_DESCRIPTOR)(pImgNtHeaders->OptionalHeader.DataDirectory[IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_IMPORT].VirtualAddress + (DWORD)pMemFile);

while(piidImportTableAddr->Name != 0)
{
    //Itterate over every IMAGE_IMPORT_DESCRIPTOR structure, extracting the names of the DLLs to import
    char* name = (char*)((DWORD)piidImportTableAddr->Name + (DWORD)pMemFile);

    //Do nothing for now

    piidImportTableAddr++;
}
```

However, the piidImportTableAddr structure's members contain addresses that are bad pointers, here is a table of the members:

```
Characteristics 0x42746553
OriginalFirstThunk 0x42746553
TimeDateStamp 0x646f4d6b
ForwarderChain 0x02260065
Name 0x54746547
FirstThunk 0x4d747865
```

These are all bad RVA's and memory locations. Is there something I'm doing wrong when looking up the DLL name by this method? I have compared the RVA of the import table to the one that is shown in PE Lord, they are the same, so I am not sure why the IMAGE_IMPORT_DESCRIPTORs are incorrect.

Here is a link to the source code in it's entirety: http://pastebin.com/32MBEvWU

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the RVA of the import table, but since the module hasn't been loaded the sections are still in their physical locations. The physical offset of the import section is usually different from the RVA. You will have to iterate through the section headers (_IMAGE_SECTION_HEADER), and using the `VirtualAddress` and `VirtualSize` values find the section that contains the import table. Then get the physical address of that section from `PointerToRawData`.

So the actual address you want is something like this:

```
importTableRVA - importSectionRVA + importSectionPhysicalAddress + pMemFile
```

Comment: Sorry, can you explain that further? I understand the abstract of what you are saying, however I don't quite understand the difference between the "import table" and the "import section".

Comment: @Dylan: PE files are divided in to sections, with different section for code, data, imports, exports etc. Usually the import section is named ".idata". But the section layout in the file is not the same as the layout of the loaded module, so that's why you have to adjust the address. I recommend reading microsoft's own documentation at: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg463125

Comment: @Dylan: And just to clarify, the import section usually *contains* the import table along with the import address tables and maybe some other data. The specification is quite leanient so any section could really contain almost anything.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. After some quick research, it seems that I would find the offset that the table is at by finding a section that the import table RVA falls into, subtracting the import section virtual address, and then adding the sections PointerToRawData. I never would have guessed that, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Your code gives the impression that your are inspecting the IAT of a module thats already been virtualized (loaded into memory), which means the IAT will not contain RVA's, but instead the addresses will have been adjusted by the windows loader to the required dynamic offsets.

However, with that being said, the data reported by LordPE is suspect, if the binary module is actually valid (ie: windows can load it and it runs), then you might be dealing with an obfuscated file, else the binary is corrupt or not a win32 PE file.

Comment: Ah, the module that I am inspecting is loaded into the program as a memory mapped file, and it has not been touched by the Windows PE loader. The module that I'm testing is notepad.exe, so it isn't obfuscated.